Print v8 internal stack trace when calling a javascript function from v8-debug shell
Is there any way to see the internal stack trace in V8 engine?
For example, I have the following in v8-debug shell:
"test".toLocaleUpperCase()
I would like to see the internal stack trace somehow (which functions where called on c++ side).
Is there a simple way to do this?

Attach a debugger and step through the code. At this point the stack layout you are looking for has not even been generated yet.

Assuming you are running d8 (e.g. the debug build of v8), are you using a debug build that you created yourself building v8 from source?
